# Find longest substring of vowels

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, regex

I have input where user types a string and I need to find longest chain of vowels in that string and render it out. I tried it by myself, but I am not sure how to do it. Here is my code:

```js
vowelHandler = () => {
    let input = document.getElementById('input2'); 
    const hasVowel = /[aeiouAEIOU]/g;
    let letters = []; 
    let vowels = ''; 
    let count = 0;
    let res = 0;
    letters = input.value.match(/[aeiouAEIOU]/g); 
    if(hasVowel.test(letters)) { 
      for(let i = 0; i <= letters.length; i++) {
        if(hasVowel.test(letters[i])) {
          count++;
          res = Math.max(res, count);
        }else {
          res = Math.max(res, count);
          count = 0;
        }
      }
      letters = letters.join(' ');
      vowels = letters.substring(letters[res]);
      document.getElementById('num2').innerHTML= vowels;
    }else {
      document.getElementById('num2').innerHTML= 'String does not contain vowels.';
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input2'/>
<button onClick={this.vowelHandler}>CLICK</button>
<p id='num2'></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
vowelHandler = () => {
    let input = document.getElementById('input2'); 
    const hasVowel = /[aeiouAEIOU]+/g;
    const letters = input.value.match(hasVowel);
    if (letters) {
        const longest = letters.reduce((acc, val) => acc.length > val.length ? acc : val, '');
        document.getElementById('num2').innerHTML= longest;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('num2').innerHTML= 'String does not contain vowels.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could replace everything in the string that is not a vowel with a white space, split the string by white space, and check which of these substrings is the longest.

```js
function getLongestVowelSubstring(s) {
  const separateVowels = s.replace(/[^aeiou]/ig, ' ').split(' ');

  const longest = separateVowels.reduce((longest, vowelGroup) => {
    return vowelGroup.length > longest.length ? vowelGroup : longest;
  }, '');

  return longest;
}

console.log(getLongestVowelSubstring('get the looongest vowel substring'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this working example:

```js
let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
function largestVowel(inputStr) {
  let largestStr = '';
  let tempVowelStr = '';
  inputStr.split('').forEach(char => {
    if (vowels.includes(char.toLowerCase())) {
      tempVowelStr += char;
      if (tempVowelStr.length > largestStr.length) {
        largestStr = tempVowelStr;
      }
    } else {
      tempVowelStr = '';
    }
  })
  return (largestStr.length === 0) ? 'String does not contain vowels.' : largestStr;
}

console.log(largestVowel('ertyyfouigdg'));

console.log(largestVowel('sdfsfsf'));

console.log(largestVowel('sdeefsfiaeosf'));
```

Complexity: **`O(n)`**